# showing front and back camera at a time in one surface

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, surfaceview

I have open camera preview for many times in surface view..but this time it is really challenging.I have to show front and back camera in same time in one surface view..I have no idea how to deal with this .

Please guide me..any tutorial will be very helpful for me..I am showing the preview which I have to do with front and back cameras

[image: the back camera in upper part and front camera in lower part]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25144412/192373 and the linked questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like described in the API:

> Your application should only have one Camera object active at a time
>   for a particular hardware camera.

here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open%28%29

So, it is not possible and not recommended to use two camera objects at the same time.

Comment: thanks for your quick replay,it means that I am unable to achieve my goal..I have tried a lot to release first camera before using the second one but it is not useful..if you have any suggestion then pls guide me..

Comment: The quote is correct, but the interpretation is wrong. The official document carefully uses the words not to restrict the case when a device has more than one hardware cameras, please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/25144412/192373.