# Opening of Front Camera and Back Camera simultaneously?

Tags: android, camera

How can i open both front camera and back camera at the same time in android? Is it possible?

I have tried tried but my application stops unfortunately.
Please Help..

Comment: Can you show some code please ? And the error ?

Comment: Assuming you could, where would the preview go?  You'd have to run two views simultaneously, side by side.

Answer (score 3):

On some devices, e.g. based on Snapdragon 805, you simply can. In other cases, the manufacturer chose to block the naïve approach, but the native camera app knows how to do it, and, with some reverse engineering effort, you can reproduce their approach (I had partial success with Samsung S4 before I lost interest in that project).

But on most of available phones, there is a physical restriction: the two cameras share the same bus, and cannot be opened simultaneously, no matter how skillful you are in software.

Comment: Hey Alex thanks for the answer.I tried alot..!
Yaaa.. and you are right. Its hardware restriction.. :-)