# Any Android Device Allowing Access to Front and Rear Cameras?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I realize this question has been asked and answered several times in the past.  Many of the answers were out dated and a bit nebulous, so I have decided to ask again.  I am working on a project that requires me access both the front and the rear cameras on an android device simultaneously.

I have tried this using the deprecated CAMERA api using [Jens Grubert's AndroidDualCameraCapture](https://bitbucket.org/jens_grubert/androiddualcameracapture).  I have also tried the using camera2 API and the Samsung SCamera api on Samsung devices.  I have run test apps across multiple devices including Moto X, S5, S6, S6 Edge, S7, S8, Pixel, and Lenovo Tango.  In all of my test cases, I have not been able to access both the front and rear camera simultaneously.

I have scoured many of the previous questions on this topic:

- [Using both front and back cameras simultaneously android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419940/using-both-front-and-back-cameras-simultaneously-android)
- [access both front and back camera simultaneously on samsung galaxy devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33626115/access-both-front-and-back-camera-simultaneously-on-samsung-galaxy-devices)
- [Is it possible to use front and back Camera at same time in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382322/is-it-possible-to-use-front-and-back-camera-at-same-time-in-android)
- [Access both back and front cameras simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30377081/access-both-back-and-front-cameras-simultaneously/30444841)
- [Opening of Front Camera and Back Camera simultaneously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25143922/opening-of-front-camera-and-back-camera-simultaneously/25144412#25144412)
- [Are there any Android Devices or any method can open front and back camera at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27276434/are-there-any-android-devices-or-any-method-can-open-front-and-back-camera-at-th/43445064)

While many of these questions list older Phones that have been proven to work, such as the HTC M8, and Nexus 6, I'm wondering if anybody has successfully accessed both cameras on a modern Android Device.  If you have, I would love to know the specific device that you have working and what API you are using.

Comment: Just a side note..its not a good idea to access them simultaneously.Your application should only have one Camera object active at a time for a particular hardware camera. says android dev docs

Comment: A link would be nice if that is indeed the case.

Comment: *if anybody has successfully accessed both cameras on a modern Android Device*  — depends on your definition of "modern". Is Nexus 6 less modern than Galaxy S5?

Answer (score 0):

I own the LG V20...it allows up to 4 separate screens. 2 front and 2 back

Answer (score 0):

that's something devices independent and "rom" independent, I got a vivo x20 with android 7.0 work, but android 8.0 no way